# What are the differences between GtkEntry and GtkTextView?

Tags: gtk, gtktextview, gtkentry

Apart from GTextView being multiline and able to display text in different styles (font, color etc. using tags), what are other obvious differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `GtkEntry` and `GtkTextView` can be multiline.

`GtkTextView` can in addition:

- Does not store any data, it uses GtkTextBuffer for that
- Several `GtkTextView` widgets can display the same content
- Be serialized to disk as RTF
- Contain other `GtkWidget`s
- Support advanced buffer manipulation through the `GtkTextBuffer` api

Answer (score 0):

I think those are the big differences. They are meant to accomplish different tasks.